# SlickGrid: unselect all rows in

Tags: slickgrid

How can I unselect all rows in a Slick Grid?

I'm using RowSelectionModel and can't find a way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectedRanges([]);
```

Comment: If you have only one row, sometimes the highlight disappears, but if you try to click in the row you can't select it again. It is like the row is already selected, but not highlighted... Can I remove focus from a row?

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but this worked for me:

```
grid.setSelectedRows([]);
```

From the [official API](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#wiki-setSelectedRows)